# automativ thread starting in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

i want a thread to start automaticalyy when my application on tmocat is started.
How do i do that.Do i have to add something to web.xml??

Answer (score 2):

You may do this with a SerlvetContextListener.

Create a class that implements the ServletContextListener interface:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ApplicationStartup implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // Do work here...
    // new Thread().start(); etc...
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
     // Stop work here if required
  }
}
```

Add your class to the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2.3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Listeners -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>ApplicationStartup</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to start your own threads in Tomcat or any other Java EE container (many related questions here in SO). You will be better off using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler.